# Highcharts: Multiple Columnrange with point inside of each of them

Tags: highcharts

Let's say I am doing temperature graph for 2 cities. I want to have minimum and maximum temperature for each month and average month temperature in one bar.

I have found (and changed a bit) an example which works perfectly for one city ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6fha9he/1/)). That's the result I want.

```
Stackoverflow wants me to put some code here because of jsfiddle, 
but I really don't know if it is good idea to paste here allt that
long JS code
```

However I need it for two (or more) cities for each month. For now, I have this ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6fha9he/)), but the average points are not placed inside of bars, instead the appear somewhere in the middle.

Is there a way how to have multiple cities with average points placed inside of each bar ? I don't know what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to use `pointPlacement`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r6fha9he/2/ - however it looks a bit problematic, because value depends on the number of points and height for the chart. Another solution may be to wrap `drawPoints` method in columnrange series, and render there extra shapes to indicate averages. Of course, that means shape without the tooltip, so probably `tooltip.formatter` would be necessary to show extra info about an average per point.

Comment: Could you please make an answer using `drawPoint` - it looks like that is what would fit me needs and answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but should be good starting point:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.columnrange.prototype, 'drawPoints', function(p) {
        var s = this,
            chart = s.chart,
            xAxis = s.xAxis,
            yAxis = s.yAxis,
            path, x, y,
            r = chart.renderer,
            radius = s.barW / 2;

        p.call(this);

        H.each(this.points, function(p) {
            if(p.options.avg) {

                y = yAxis.toPixels(p.options.avg * (-1), true); 
                x = p.plotX + s.columnMetrics.offset + radius;

                path = [ 
                    'M', x - radius, y - radius, 
                    'L', x + radius, y - radius,
                    'L', x + radius, y + radius,
                    'L', x - radius, y + radius,
                    'Z'
                    ];

                if(p.avgShape) {
                    p.avgShape.attr({
                        d: path
                    });
                } else {
                    p.avgShape = r.path(path).attr({
                        fill: s.options.avgColor
                    }).add(s.group);
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(Highcharts)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r6fha9he/3/

One hacky thing to mention - values are multiplied by *(-1), because `toPixels()` won't recognize inverted chart, and I would like to avoid using `axis.translate()`. The same is not necessary for non-inverted chart. In case you are more interested in `translate`, search source code for:

> /** 
>   * Translate from axis value to pixel position on the chart, or back
>   *
>   */
>   translate: function (val, backwards, cvsCoord, old, handleLog, pointPlacement) {